# How do you search for a local font by it's PostScript Name?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, windows

How do you search for a local font based on it's PostScript Name?

[I found this nifty way to generate a list of PostScript names for Mac computers but that doesn't help me at all here, below is an example.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275493/261273)

[image]

I'm looking for a Windows solution. A way to search a collection of fonts by their PostScript name. Not a list generator like in the example above.

**Note:  PostScript name is different than the font file name. This is important for programs or operating systems that identify the fonts differently.**

Comment: @Scott Its related because Adobe Illustrator detects missing fonts using their PostScript name in Windows instead of it's font name. The PostScript name is not listed in the Windows font manager. It's the only way to install the correct fonts in Windows. That's why it's graphic design related.

Comment: So it was migrated in the end... :V

Comment: @PepeOchoa I think it was a mistake. Anyway the important thing is if someone now tries to google how to search for a font by it's PostScript name they will be able to find a solution! I don't want anyone to have to go through what I did trying to research this.

Comment: Lateral, I didn't mean to imply it was completely out of left field. But the nature of the question isn't related to design at all. And merely because an application is used in a profession, everything related to that application isn't necessarily related to the field. I.E. plumbers may use Quickbooks. That doesn't make every Quickbooks question plumbing related.

Comment: @Scott fair enough. As long as it's out there on SE and people can find it!

Answer (score 1):

I made a little script in Python 2, hope it works. The Community is welcome to correct/enhance it, since I don't really code in Python yet.

```
import _winreg
sstr = raw_input("PS Name to look for:")
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts", 0, _winreg.KEY_READ)
for i in xrange(0, _winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[1]):
    dafont = _winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
    if sstr.lower().encode('utf8') in dafont[0].lower().encode('utf8'):
        print dafont[0], ':', dafont[1]
```

You can enter part of the name and it will search for all fonts with a matching name.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator, run this as a jsx and input the font name you want to find.

```
#target illustrator

var count, i, find, log="Fonts found:\n";
find = prompt ("Find font name:","Arial");
count = textFonts.length;
for (i=0; i<count; i++)
{ if (textFonts[i].name.match (find) == find)
  { log = log + textFonts[i].name + "\n";
  }
}
alert (log);
```

If you search the default of "Arial", it will return something like the image linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RaK8.jpg) (depending on your installed fonts).

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1 (Nexusfont )

1. Download **[nexusfont](http://www.xiles.net/)** **(FREE)**
2. (Optional) Uninstall all fonts except for Windows that came with Windows. (To prevent conflicts)
3. Organize fonts and then search for PostScript name.
4. Right click properties and it will give you more details on the naming.

Pros: Gives a lot of details. Doubles as a great FontManager with live type preview capabilities. Install and uninstall fonts directly from nexusfont.

Cons: None!

## Option 2 (Windows Explorer Method)

1. Do **NOT** use Windows Font manager to search. It does not search PostScript names.
2. (Optional) Uninstall all fonts except for Windows that came with Windows. (To prevent conflicts)
3. Move all your fonts to a folder outside of the "Windows Font
   Manager Folder." search your PostScript name in the search field. It
   will show all fonts that contain that PostScript name.
4. To see the PostScript Name: Right click -> Properties -> Details -> Title

Cons: Cannot read all the details because windows explorer is stupid and cuts it off with no way to expand the properties window.

Pros: Do not need to download additional software.

---

Dishonorable mentions (stay clear unless you already have these):

1. **Free trial of Suitcase Fusion by Extensis.**
   That's because it's $119.95 and it's really not that good except for the "Auto Activation" which doesn't really work all the time.
2. **Universal Type Server by Extensis.** Because it's so expensive they don't list the price and it doesn't manage a local database. It's slow and constantly crashes.

---

I could not find any other type manager that searched PostScript names with the ability to install and uninstall fonts. If anyone else has some other font managers that can do this comment and I will add them to the list. Thank you!

Comment: [FontExplorer X can search by PostScript name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voaof.png), on Mac at least, no idea what the Windows version is like but I don't see why it would be any different

Comment: @Cai That's useful for our Mac friends. It's because the included Windows font manager isn't really much of a font manager at all. It's incredibly basic.